# Не могу решить уравнение: |-x|+|-y|=|4-x|+|2-y|

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра, уравнения

Рассматриваю на трех промежутках следующую совокупность уравнений (может в этом проблема), подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так, ибо с графическим решением ответ не сходится:

1. x<0, y<0, x+y=4-x+2-y или x<0, 0<y<2, x-y=4-x+2-y или x<0, y>2, x-y=4-x-2+y
2. 0<x<4, y<0, -x+y=4-x+2-y или 0<x<4, 0<y<2, -x-y=4-x+2-y или 0<x<4, y>2, -x-y=4-x-2+y
3. x>4, y<0, -x+y=-4+x+2-y или x>4, 0<y<2, - x-y=-4+x+2-y или x>4, y>2, -x-y=-4+x-2+y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы так долго с этим разбираетесь, что не выдержал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, смотрите...

Comment: Это, кстати, диаграмма Вороного `L_1` пары точек. Если много точек получаются красивые картинки. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#/media/File:Manhattan_Voronoi_Diagram.svg

Comment: Спасибо вам! Я же правильно понимаю, что если внутри модуля с учетом стоявшего минуса в выражении |-x| оно будет положительным, то раскрываем его с плюсом, то есть просто снимаем модуль. Если внутри отрицательное, то меняем знак?)

Comment: Ну да. При `x<0` `|-x|==|x|==-x`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, я её и строила) Осталось теперь построить такую же в метрике Чебышева:)

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, поняла, что затупила знатно)

Comment: Голосом Юматова в роли Трофимова :) — Бывает...

Comment: В метрике Чебышева (которая L_inf) вы получите ту же картинку повёрнутую на 45 градусов. Когда поймёте почему, разрешаю прыгать вокруг стола от радости. :)
Откуда вы взяли эту задачу?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, возможно не поверите, но учусь на 3 курсе матфака..
Сейчас вот курс машинного обучения начался

Comment: Вас учат диаграммам Вороного на странных метриках? Круто, хотя и очень специально.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Скорее очень обзорно проходим, но да, хотя бы проходим. Вы не могли бы пояснить почему на 45 градусов поворот? Ибо судя по построенным картинкам там поворот на 135 против часовой или на 45 с зеркальным отображением. Я понимаю, что эти метрики можно друг в друга преобразовывать, вращая и масштабируя, но не до конца:)

Comment: У одной единичный шар - ромб, у второй квадрат. Повороты на 45, 135, 225 и 315 градусов переводят ромб в квадрат и наоборот. И форма диаграммы Вороного полностью определяется формой единичного шара, который задаёт метрику.

Answer (score -1):

Везде, где переменные принимают отрицательные значения, их модули почему-то раскрывается со знаком +, а где положительные, модуль раскрывается с минусом, хотя все должно быть наоборот. Возможно, Вы забыли, что |-x| = |x|, и отсюда все ошибки. Рекомендую пересмотреть этот момент. Правильная система должна выглядеть так:

1. x<0, y<0, -x-y=4-x+2-y или x<0, 0<y<2, -x+y=4-x+2-y или x<0, y>2,
   -x-y=4-x-2+y
2. 0<x<4, y<0, x-y=4-x+2-y или 0<x<4, 0<y<2, x-y=4-x+2-y
   или 0<x<4, y>2, x-y=4-x-2+y
3. x>4, y<0, x-y=-4+x+2-y или x>4, 0<y<2, x-y=-4+x+2-y или x>4, y>2, x-y=-4+x-2+y